# Browser: Make an HTTPS GET request to API that uses self-signed certificate. Programmatically without any work on the user side

Tags: javascript, ssl, browser, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I need to call an HTTPS REST API (Kubernetes) that uses self-signed certificates (almost all Kubernetes clusters are like that).

I have the cluster's root CA certificate (and also the client certificate. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster.MasterAuth))

How can I make this HTTPS GET request **in browser** and **without user interaction** (e.g. without asking the users to download and install the CA certificate)?

Using plain `fetch` throws the `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. The `axios` library documentation is pretty confusing regarding what they support, and I'm not sure they support  CAs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make this HTTPS GET request in browser and without user interaction (e.g. without asking the users to download and install the CA certificate)?

You can't do this with your setup. Browsers will only accept certificates issued by predefined trusted certificate issuers. If there would be a way to silently accept anything outside of this then stealth man in the middle attacks would be easy.

Therefore you have to options: make the user accept your certificate or get a certificate issued by a public CA. Given that such certificates can be free the latter option is likely the easier one.

Comment: Kubernetes auto-generates it's own certificates and service accounts. I'm not sure I can just easily force it to use not self-signed certs.

Comment: I wonder whether this is really impossible. There are WebSockets, there are streaming protocols etc. I understand that `fetch()` is likely a dead end, but it's not the only way to send TCP packets, right?

Comment: @Ark-kun: It is as I said, no matter if you like the answer :) But you might try to solve the wrong problem in the first place. The typical setup is that there is a some kind of reverse proxy (like a load balancer) where the clients TLS gets terminated. And at this "entry point" publicly trusted certificates will be used. The internal certificates should not matter for a client accessing from the public internet.

Comment: I see. I guess it's just surprising for me that the were are WebSockets and WebRTC and all of the network streaming technologies, but no full-fledged HTTP support built with those network technologies. The problem I'm solving is definitely wrong - I should not be solving this problem - the GKE API should just expose the APIs for managing the Kubernetes objects in the cluster instead of only having APIs to manipulate the clusters as black boxes.

Comment: "The typical setup is that there is a some kind of reverse proxy": Interesting. This happens to be true in most of my case. Unfortunately I do not know how to programmatically find those proxy endpoints.